# How do I get a Rails 1.2.6 to automatically load code from app/*

Tags: ruby-on-rails, legacy

I have a Rails 1.2.6 application and I would like to be able to create a folder in app/ and have its contents loaded.

This is the behaviour of Rails 3. How can I achieve the same thing in Rails 1.2.6?

Comment: see the rebuilding rails book, it explains in details how to use ConstMissing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in config/environment.rb

```
config.load_paths += Dir["#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/jobs"]
```